# PHP - Is file being written to?

Tags: php, file

My mailserver writes to a file every minute, this is fine and I'm happy for it to do that.

However on my WebServer, I want to check if that file is currently being written to and if it isn't, show the user a download link.

Is there any way I can do this..

For example: run a loop that will keep looking until the file is no longer being written to then, show a download link to the file?

I've read about `flock()` but I don't think this will help as another process / os is actually creating the file!

Comment: Do you want to lock the file to let the user download it?

Comment: Don't bother. In the time it takes the user to accept the download another write operation could fire off. Also, it doesn't matter if the file is being written to because a read request will either go through normally, or be queued a few microseconds until the write finishes depending on the type of write handle that is open on the file. Whatever the case, the write operation will not be interrupted *unless* you start doing weird crap like trying to lock the file for a *read* operation of all things.

Comment: Ideally I just want the link to be present so the user can download the file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writting script/app/process should write lock file (empty file like `filename.lock` before it starts writting to main file, and then it shall remove when done. It's regular locking approach but the your script will just need to check if `filename.lock` is present or not. If it is, then file is being written to.

Answer (score 0):

You can only acquire a read or write lock if no-one else is currently writing. You shouldn't have to do this.

Also, when the user downloads the file it could be the file has changed in the mean time. Are you sure you've got the right mental image of what you want?